# C++11 CMake: Regex fails

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, cmake, g++4.9

I ran into the problem that gcc/g++ <= 4.8.X does not support RegEx (my first reaction was: WHAT?!).

After installing (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS) gcc-4.9 and g++-4.9 (which is supposed to support RegEx properly) I still the get same error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():  regex_error
[1]    13608 abort (core dumped)
```

My **CMakeLists.txt** looks like this (working with Jetbrains CLion as IDE):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++-4.9)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(project1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(project1 ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

My **code** looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

(...)

char encryptChar(char cinput)
{
    std::string s = std::string(1, cinput);
    // simplified regex (also crashes)
    std::regex e = std::regex("[a-z]");

    if(std::regex_match(s, e))
    {
        // do some stuff, if string matches conditions
    }

    return cinput;
}
```

Compiler/Linker do not complain about anything. Program runs fine without the regex-lines.

```
> g++-4.9 --version
>>> g++-4.9 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-0ubuntu1~14.04) 4.9.2
>>> Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

**EDIT**: After manually compiling the code with `g++-4.9 -std=c++11 main.cpp` the regex works. Why does the IDE/CMake version fails?

Comment: We need more specific version information. Compiler and standard library implementation.

Comment: Apart from the fact you are using cannon on the sparrow, the code looks ok and runs fine.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit What kind of further information do you need? I don't really get what "standard library implementation" could mean^^

Comment: @Erbureth So if the code runs fine on your PC I guess I'm doing something wrong while compiling? What do you exactly mean with "cannon on the sparrow" -> is there an easier solution?

Comment: @ascenator See live example: http://ideone.com/dDvonS You can try compiling it manually via `g++-4.9 -std=c++11 main.cpp -o project1` and see what happens.

Comment: @ascenator: Your toolchain has a compiler, and an implementation of the standard library. You need to tell us what the version number is of both.

Comment: As for the solution, if you are classifying input character by character, regex is adding huge overhead, you'd be better off comparing character values directly (`cinput >= 'a' && cinput <= 'z'`)

Comment: After compiling it with manually with `g++-4.9 -std=c++11 main.cpp -o project1` the program and regex works...why does the IDE/CMake version fail? oO

Comment: Just as a note, `std::regex_search` also doesn't appear to return matches with using g++ 4.8.  I spent over an hour wondering why http://cpp.sh/8ggfd wouldn't work on Ubuntu 14.04 (with g++, or even clang++-3.8) until I tried it it on cpp.sh, read this post, and realized it was 4.8's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem:

My CMake version was 2.8-ish so CMake itself failed, Jetbrains CLion uses a custom CMake (shipped with the IDE) which is some 3.1-ish but also failed with RegEx.

I downloaded [CMake 3.2.2](http://www.cmake.org/download/) (newest version) and installed it ([installation notes](http://www.cmake.org/install/)). Now compiling with CMake uses g++-4.9 properly and RegEx runs fine. In CLion I had to change the settings to ignore the custom CMake and use my systems CMake 3.2.2, now compiling with the IDE uses g++-4.9 properly, too and RegEx runs fine.